# Protractor error selenium spring boot

Tags: spring, selenium, protractor, ubuntu-16.04

```
vegan@vegan:~/hb-productupload/gateway/src/test/javascript$ gulp protractor  
[15:47:24] Working directory changed to ~/hb-productupload/gateway
[15:47:51] Using gulpfile ~/hb-productupload/gateway/gulpfile.js
[15:47:51] Starting 'protractor'...
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:47841
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1265:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:186:37)
    at /home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:276:21
    at _fulfilled (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /home/vegan/hb-productupload/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
[15:47:59] gulp-notify: [JHipster Gulp Build] Error: protractor exited with code 1
[15:47:59] Finished 'protractor' after 7.34 s
[15:47:59] E2E Tests failed
```

I am trying to run a simple

i updated chrme driver.

Then i made

```
npm install
bower install
gulp install
```

but did not work when i run

```
gulp protractor
```

I run with gulp for project but also i downloaded to my ubuntu and i can run as local. But same error for that local happens when i run

```
protractor protractor.conf.js
```

Ysterday i could run both, i made upgrade. now i cant work both.

this `is conf` file

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require("protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter");
var JasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var prefix = 'src/test/javascript/'.replace(/[^/]+/g, '..');

exports.config = {

    chromeDriver: prefix + 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    suites: {
        login: './e2e/account/login/*.js'
    },

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    directConnect: true,


    framework: 'jasmine2',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },


    onPrepare: function () {

        // Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
        var disableNgAnimate = function () {
            angular
                .module('disableNgAnimate', [])
                .run(
                    [
                        '$animate',
                        function ($animate) {
                            $animate.enabled(false);
                        }
                    ]
                );
        };

        var disableCssAnimate = function () {
            angular
                .module('disableCssAnimate', [])
                .run(
                    function () {
                        var style = document.createElement('style');
                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.innerHTML = 'body * {' +
                            '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-moz-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-o-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-ms-transition: none !important;' +
                            'transition: none !important;' +
                            '}';
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
                    }
                );
        };

        browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
        browser.addMockModule('disableCssAnimate', disableCssAnimate);

        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1280);


    }
};
```

this is in protractor config

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.51.0",
    "chromedriver": "2.25",
    "iedriver": "2.51.0"
  }
}
```

it was not 2.25 i  updated but still same.

Comment: There has been many times I needed to uninstall and delete all instances of npm and protract.  Have you tried that?

Comment: No because npm is working correctly for front end. IT is also not about protractor in mmy local because there is also protractor inside gulp. BOth of them are not woking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed chrome driver and selenium driver to latest and it worked.