# Can not run webdriver manager

Tags: node.js, selenium, gulp, protractor, webdriver-manager

When i run

> > vegan@vegan:~/xx-xx/gateway$ webdriver-manager start /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/logger.js:66
> >         info(...msgs) {
> >              ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/index.js:8:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

i got error. It started when protractor doesnot run.

the error was that

[Protractor error selenium spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423792/protractor-error-selenium-spring-boot)

but this time updating version, did not work. So i did npm install, bower gulp install after i deleing node module file.

now for gulp run ( i use gulp to run protractor), i got this

```
> gulp protractor prod [15:47:58] Using gulpfile
> ~/xx-xx/gateway/gulpfile.js [15:47:58] Starting 'protractor'...
> [15:47:58] Starting 'prod'... [15:47:58] Finished 'prod' after 547 μs
> Using ChromeDriver directly... [launcher] Running 1 instances of
> WebDriver [launcher] Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/xx-xx/gateway/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:7:17)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10) [launcher] Process exited with error code 100 [15:47:59] gulp-notify: [JHipster
> Gulp Build] Error: protractor exited with code 100 [15:47:59] Finished
> 'protractor' after 1.19 s [15:47:59] E2E Tests failed
```

**UPDATE**

**i deleted all node modules and did npm install again. Now when i do 
**webdriver-manager** it gives errors
**

```
webdriver-manager 
/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/logger.js:66
    info(...msgs) {
         ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/cli/index.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)**
```

**

or for **webdriver-manager update
** same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error on webdriver-manager 10.2.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929821/syntax-error-on-webdriver-manager-10-2-9)

Answer (score 3):

It's due to you are using an older version of node. Please update your node version to min. 6.9.x and try it would certainly work.

Comment: i updated to 7.4.0but still got 8:57:59] Finished 'qa' after 1.29 ms
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
(node:19785) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

/home/vegan/xx-xx/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:47959

Comment: you have to shutdown your already running selenium server, you can do it by `webdriver-manager shutdown` and start it again

Comment: WHen i do it says Invalid command
Usage: webdriver-manager <command>

Comment: This is the solution to the problem (update node). Thanks.